# how to increase max_locks_per_transaction using docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am working on a project and I am using docker.

In docker there are

_postges_1 postgres:13.4-alpine

and

_pgadmin_1 dpage/pgadmin4:5.6

and here is docker-compose.ylm file

```
version: '2.4'

services:
    node-app:
        container_name: node-app
        environment:
            NODE_ENV: '${NODE_ENV}'
            PORT: 8080
            HOST: '${HOST}'
            DB_NAME: '${DB_NAME}'
            TEST_DB_NAME: '${TEST_DB_NAME}'
            DB_USERNAME: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            DB_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            DB_HOST: '${DB_HOST}'
        ports:
            - '80:8080'
        restart: always
        mem_limit: '3072M'
        volumes:
            - /tmp:/home/node/app/secrets
            - '${EB_LOG_BASE_DIR}/node-app:/home/node/app/logs'

    pgadmin:
        image: 'dpage/pgadmin4:5.6'
        environment:
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: 'root@example.com'
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 'root'
        volumes:
            - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
        ports:
            - '5050:80'
        restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
    pgadmin:
```

Whenever I start the server locally I am getting **out of shared memory** and I want to increase *max_locks_per_transaction*.